# Some @2x images referenced from storyboard not loaded on iPad2 in iOS8

Tags: ios, image, storyboard, resolution

The app has many images at @2x resolution, and only some are included at @1x resolution (the ones that do not downscale nicely). This appears to work fine. (And, yes I'm aware of the issues in this decision.)

However, on iPad2 running iOS8 (simulator), **some** images referenced from storyboard are not loaded.

```
Could not load the "ScrollView-Separator.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier
```

Note, that all other images that are referenced similarly (i.e. only by the storyboard) and only have @2x resolution are loaded and downscaled as expected.

`ScrollView-Separator@2x~ipad.png` definitely exists on in the app.

The symptom is not seen on iPad2 running iOS7.1 (simulator and device) - images are loaded and downscaled as expected (or retina iPad simulator - @2x images shown). (I don't want to upgrade my device merely to test whether it is a simulator-only issue.)

I have tried removing the `.png` in the storyboard reference, but that does not fix the problem. The same warning is seen without `.png` in the filename.

It looks like a bug, but seems dependent on particular files, perhaps their size in points, perhaps?

It has me confused.

Comment: Check names for case-sensitivity, probably you have some differences there. Also make sure those files are attach to proper bundle. http://i.stack.imgur.com/g6d2F.jpg

Comment: @Grzegorz The thing is that the image name must be right and the image must be in the app because it works on iOS7.1 and retina. I can see the file in the app contents and it has correct case. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Are you using assets catalogs or you use files directly?

Comment: @Grzegorz No, not for this project. The images are added as individual files.

Comment: I have the same problem and i tested it with an iPad mini with iOS8, all the images that are loaded using the storyboard that only have @2x version suffer from this, i.e. does not load if have image@2x.png and/or image@2x~ipad.png, but it does load if i have either image.png or image~ipad.png (maybe your "some images" are not loaded because there isn't the-image.png or the-image~pad.png?) The only thing i could do is for every x@2x~ipad.png create the corresponding x~ipad.png, in case there isn't any x@2x~ipad.png, just create the x.png.